# OSMnx custom_filter - get all types of roads

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geocoding, osmnx

I need to get all existing OSM types of roads from the area, and I'm searching for a simple way of doing this rather than specifying each type with "|"

I've tried to write something like this:

```
place_name = "Moscow"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all", custom_filter="%s")
```

or just

```
place_name = "Moscow"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all", custom_filter="highway")
```

However, in the first one I've received an error while the second one did not return all existing OSM values

I've scanned OSMnx documentation, but haven't found any shortcuts for all types of roads: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html

Comment: I suggest you install QGIS then install the OSM downloader  plugin. You just zoom to the area of interest then download your cover of OSM data.

Comment: Thank you, but I was asking about the syntax in OSMnx for collecting all types of roads from the area

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to the documentation https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html so that others better understand that you are not interested in the standard OSM data.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76916481/7321942

Answer (score 0):

I would try without custom_filtering.

```
place_name = "Moscow"
G = ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type="all", custom_filter=None")
```

See the documentation:

> network_type (string {"all_private", "all", "bike", "drive",
> "drive_service", "walk"}) – what type of street network to get if
> custom_filter is None